# Why should I use AWS RDS/DynamoDB instead of putting everything inside an EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Currently I'm hosting my IPB forums on a single high-end OVH dedicated server without any tech issues. I'm considering moving to AWS and AWS recommends (??) you to host your web app on a EC2 (or ELB if you want scalability) and host your database separately on RDS/DynamoDB (RDS on my use case).

I have almost 5k CCU during peak hours and 50GB+ database.

Why should I use AWS RDS/DynamoDB instead of putting everything inside an EC2? Isn't that more expansive?

Comment: While this is a good question in general, it is not a good fit for SO because it can take hundreds of pages to explain why you should not do that. To put is simply, if you have one instance, then this instance is single point of failure in your architecture. If this instance goes down, everything goes down. While this approach may "work" for small, noncritical projects, it is impossible to run Google on a single machine.

Comment: Yes, but we are not talking about Google. We are talking about a relatively small community that already runs on a single server. Yes, I understand that downtime is possible, but again, not Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it all on Ec2 (not dynamodb, there is no production version that you can run local), but a db like mysql or anything else that can be installed on the instance - then you are responsible for backing it up, apply patches etc.

I for years ran web apps on ec2 using a local SQL Server database, and they worked just fine.

However, once I moved my databases to RDS I slept a *lot* better. I no longer need to worry about an instance crashing in the middle of the night and losing customer data - I pay AWS to worry about it for me.

So, yes, technically it's possible - and it will even work - until something goes very wrong. If you are fanatical about doing your backups, storing them somewhere safe, and applying all required patches - you may be fine; I'd rather pay AWS, but it will absolutely work and you can always upgrade later.